# Deleting a cookie in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

I can't seem to get a cookie to delete, or expire, or at least update in Chrome. I'm using the value of a cookie to test if a user is logged in, and without the cookie expiring, or being deleted, or the value changed, it's not logging the user out.

Below is the code I'm using when the user clicks on logout:

```
$_COOKIE['user'] = '';
unset($_COOKIE['user']);
setcookie('user', '', time() - (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
```

(lines 2 and 3 have been tried in alternate order with no change)

When I go to another page and then back to a page that requires password protection it's still registering me as logged in. If I look at the cookie in Chrome within the settings, it's showing the cookie content and expiry date (a month from now) as being unchanged.

### UPDATED

Including all code for the page here, hoping it will help.

```
<?php

    $preset_username = "username";
    $preset_password = "userpassword";

    //Setting values to nothing the first time page loads
    $message = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $redirect = "";
    $height = "height: 380px;";


    //This code is run when someone clicks on the login button
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        //Saves the username and password entered into the textboxes
        $username = trim($_POST['user']);
        $password = trim($_POST['pword']);


        //Checks to see if the username and password entered match the preset username and password
        if ($username == $preset_username && $password == $preset_password) {
            if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || $_COOKIE['user'] == '') {
                setcookie('user', 'true', time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");  //86400 = 1 day
                $_COOKIE['user'] = 'true';
            }

            //Checks to see if there's a page saved that they should be redirected to once they've logged in
            if (isset($_COOKIE['redirect_to'])) {
                $redirect_address = $_COOKIE['redirect_to'];

                //Performs redirection if using cookies 
                $redirect = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">location.href = '";
                $redirect .= $redirect_address;
                $redirect .= "';</script>";

                echo $redirect;
            }

            //Redirects to the page they came from
            echo $redirect;           

        }
        elseif ($username == "logout" && $password == "logout") {

            //This logs the person out if they enter "logout" as the username and password (testing purposes)
            if(!isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
                $_COOKIE['user'] = '';
                unset($_COOKIE['user']);
                setcookie('user', '', time() - (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");                
            }            

            $height = "height: 400px;";             //Resets the height - Used with the css
            $message = "<p style=\"color: darkblue; text-align: center;\">You have been logged out</p>";

        }
        else {
            //Resets the height - Used with the css
            $height = "height: 440px;";

            //Sets an error message if the person enters the wrong login information
            $message = "<p style=\"color: 4C4646; text-align: center;\">Incorrect Login <br /> Please check your login name and password and try again.</p>";
        }
    }

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>

  <title>REMOVED</title>

  <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url('http://domain.com/images/images2.jpg');
        }

        #container {
            position: absolute;
            <?php echo $height; ?>
            width: 700px;
            margin: 250px auto 0px auto;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            background-image:url('http://domain.com/images/beige031.jpg');
        }

        #content {
            width: 650px; 
            font-family: Times New Roman; 
            font-size: 18pt;
            color: #3B3131;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <p style="text-align: justify;">This page ...</p>

        <?php echo $message; ?>

        <div style="width: 700px;">

            <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

                <p style="text-align: justify; padding-top: 10px;">
                    Login:<input name="user" type="text" />


                <p style="text-align: justify;">
                    Password:<input name="pword" type="password" />
                </p>

                <input value="Login" name="submit" type="submit" />

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And by "back", you mean the "back" button, which usually loads a page from cache? Or did you actually reload the page?

Comment: I'm reloading the page.

Comment: Reloading and back. On each page that requires a login, I'm actively checking on load for the cookie using !isset or a value of "", and the actual cookie in Chrome when I check after the logout doesn't seem to change at all.

Comment: Can you inspect the HTTP headers sent on that page? Could it be that you already `echo`'ed something before (un)setting the cookie?

Comment: I just took a look and no "echo"s.

Comment: Cookies must be set/deleted before any headers are sent.

Comment: @Beaker Are you sure there is absolutely nothing printed before that statement? No notice/warning/error? No plain HTML? No newline after the `?>` at the end of an `include`/`require`'d script?

Comment: The logout function is using a form at the moment for testing purposes. So, when logging in a cookie is set (a different one) which is working fine, and when logging out this cookie should be deleted or at least updated. The two options are in an if/elseif, so it should only be accessing one or the other. Is that to say that a cookie can't be unset or updated as part of a $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" (above the opening <html> tag)?

Comment: @Siguza Just double checked to confirm. There is an include that I'm using on all pages, except for the page that's handling the logout, so there's nothing above that in the headers. I have an error that might get displayed, but that's in the else on the if statement I'm using, so if logging out that isn't echo'd.

Comment: Alright, I think we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Siguza Updated post to show code for the page. Hope this helps. And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This logs the person out if they enter "logout" as the username and password (testing purposes)
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']))
```

So you log them out only when they're not logged in... need I say more?

Comment: Next time if something doesn't work, just put an `echo` next to it to see if that code actually runs. ;)